# How to read multiple lines from a fixed width input text file?

Tags: file, text, input, width, fixed

I'm new to programming and have been struggling with this issue for a few hours now, and cannot seem to find exactly what I'm looking for online anywhere.

I want my program to read from an input file that looks similar to the following (each dot represents one space):

```
Last................First...............OtherText
```

From the file, I want to read the first string ignoring everything after, then start over and read only the middle string, then start over again and ready only the last string of text.

I have tried this using the ignore function, and have found no successful way of resetting the ignore function to start over at the beginning of the file each time:

```
inputFile1.ignore(0) >> lastName;
inputFile1.ignore(20) >> firstName;
inputFile1.ignore(49) >> transactionDate;
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

For anyone who may come across this issue, the solution for extracting specific portions of a fixed column width text file is to "trim" the areas needed using substr. My working code looks like this:

```
getline (inputFile1, inputLine1);               // Retrieve the row
lastName = inputLine1.substr(0,20);             // Extract columns
firstName = inputLine1.substr(20,20);
transactionDate = inputLine1.substr(49,10);
```

The first number associated to substr represents the columns you wish to ignore and the second number represents the columns you wish to retrieve.